# How to pass hashmap to jsp from servlet request.setatttibute

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

How to pass linkedhashmap from java servlet to jsp using `request.setatttibute()` and how to use it in the jsp`

```
LinkedHashmap<String,Person> link = new LinkedHashmap<String,Person>()
request.settattribute("hash",link)
```

Now how do I get it in the jsp and make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can put the request attribute and then get it.

```
    Map link = new LinkedHashMap();
    link.put("key", "value");
    //put map as request attribute 
    request.setAttribute("hash",link);
    //get map as request attribute from the request
    Map link1 =(Map)request.getAttribute("hash");
```

Comment: Hi buddy, i have tried this but i get an error saying Map link = new LinkedHashMap<String,Vehicle>(); even though this hashmap works in all other classes .' It says can't understand Vehicle".. Vehicle is a class in the same project.

Comment: If trying to get attribute in jsp then make sure you import Vehicle class in jsp file using page directive.

Comment: How can i do it ? Please if you could explain a bit it would be great thanks

Comment: In the top of jsp file add below: <%@ page import="<package>.Vehicle" %>    Use the proper package name of the class Vehicle

Comment: Package name is default, so should i say <default>.Vehicle

Comment: In that case just add : <%@ page import="Vehicle" %>

Comment: Thanks buddy , you are a legend

Comment: Welcome, I hope it is working now.